# Naming Active-Low Outputs

Tags: naming, embedded-systems

I'm writing some software for an embedded system. I am trying to think of clear names for my single pin output functions.

Normally, when I'm working with active-high outputs (ON = 1, OFF = 0), I am happy to call these functions "setX" and "resetX", where X is a more descriptive name for the output that I'm working with. However, some of my outputs are active-low (ON = 0, OFF = 1), and it seems bizarre to make my "setX" make the output 0.

Is there a standard naming convention for (re)setting values that are on when they're 0?

Comment: [On the troubles of naming and terminology](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6582/22815)

Comment: @Snowman: I have read that meta question. The top answer says that these types of questions are on-topic. I'm not sure if there's another quality issue that I'm missing here.

Comment: Could an affix help? E.g. `setX` says I make output `X` active, and `setXNeg` says that I make output `X` active _and_ the active level is low. Using `set`/`reset` is the lowest possible level of abstraction; if you can, use @karl-bielefeldt advice and name the function on the board, not just pin of the crystal.

Comment: Pick a naming convention and stick with it across your projects.  Using more descriptive names may help as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your software is an abstraction over the hardware.  Whether a particular signal is active low or not is a detail you are supposed to abstract away.  You should choose names to reflect that.  `set` and `reset` probably feel odd because they aren't abstract enough.  Try other verbs, such as as enable/disable, activate/deactivate, or select/deselect for a chip select pin.  If the pin has another specific purpose, use appropriate terms for that, such as transmit/receive, sleep/wake, forward/reverse, etc.